# Terraform templating question - iterating over a directory of variable files

Tags: templates, configuration, terraform

Is it possible in Terraform to iterate over a directory of files containing variables and apply each file's values to a template? In very general, non-Terraform, bad pseudo-code -- here's what I'm hoping to do:

**/varfiles/var_file1.yml**

```
User:
  Name: Jim
  Address:
    Street: 123 Main
    City: MyTown
    State: IL
    Zip: 12345
  Age: 40
  Children:
    - Beth
    - Mike
```

**/varfiles/var_file2.yml**

```
User:
  Name: Jill
  Address:
    Street: 321 Oak St
    City: UrTown
    State: IL
    Zip: 54321
  Age: 27
  Children:
    - Ricky
```

**Template Logic**

```
FOR each file in /varfiles/*(
   print(User's name is: %{file.User.Name})
   print(User's age is: %{file.User.Age})
   print(User's address is: %{file.User.Street file.User.City, file.User.State file.User.Zip})})
   IF COUNT(%{file.User.Children}) > 0 THEN (
      FOR child in %{file.User.Children}(
         print(The user has a child named: %{child})
      )
   )
)
```

Each iteration would be expected to generate a separate set of outputs - e.g. separate files.
**Expected 'output' for var_file1.yml**

```
User's name is: Jim
User's age is: 40
User's address is: 123 Main MyTown, IL 12345
The user has a child named: Beth
The user has a child named: Mike
```

**Expected 'output' for var_file2.yml**

```
User's name is: Jill
User's age is: 27
User's address is: 321 Oak Street UrTown, IL 54321
The user has a child named: Ricky
```

Solution doesn't have to implement this particular logic - but I'm not familiar enough with Terraform yet to know if it's possible at all, if this is the right approach, or if Terraform is the right tool.

The problem I'm hoping to solve is to template configuration files that would be generated on a per-user or per-role basis. Then store user or role-specific variables in separate files within a specific directory. This would make it easy to potentially manage hundreds of roles/users without having to deal with a var file that's hundreds or thousands of lines long and the dir structure and file names would make it obvious who/what was assigned what.

Comment: There is [fileset](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/fileset.html), but I'm not sure what do you want to do with your templates?

Comment: If I need 100 versions of a config file, I'd like to template the config, and have a directory of 100 (ideally yaml) files that each contain the variables required for their respective config. Does that make sense/help?